# Laravel Gate::forUser relates to authenticated user

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project (5.7.21) and I'm trying to use the Gate::forUser to determine if a user is authorized for a specific role.

I have defined the following gates and assigned the relevant roles in my db.

```
Gate::define('team_member', function () {
            return Auth::user()->hasRole('team_member');
        });
        Gate::define('shop', function () {
            return Auth::user()->hasRole('shop');
        });
```

While I'm logged on to my application, I'm trying to check if another user is authorized :

```
if (Gate::forUser($for_user)->allows('shop')){
          Debugbar::info("I am a shop user : " . $for_user->first_name);
}
elseif (Gate::forUser($for_user)->allows('team_member')){
          Debugbar::info("I am a team user : " . $for_user->first_name);
}
```

My problem is that the gate gets evaluated against the authenticated user (so my own user in this instance), and not the `$for_user` that I'm trying to impersonate... So the results are wrong.

I have checked that `$for_user` contains a valid user as expected and it does.

Have you had any similar issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first parameter when defining a new Gate resource. This is all visible in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#gates).

```
Gate::define('team_member', function ($user) {
    return $user->hasRole('team_member');
});
```